# Are points beyond box plots whiskers outliers?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, outliers

I was working on the Titanic dataset and found that after plotting the boxplot, there's a huge number of outliers (points past the whiskers).
Though, after checking the answers provided on Kaggle, I've noticed that people are not considering those points as outliers.

So, I was wondering. Is it always the case that points below Q1 - 1.5*IQR or more than Q3 + 1.5*IQR outliers?
if not, when to consider them as outliers, and when not?

This is [a link of one of the answers](https://www.kaggle.com/vikasbz/titanic-survivors-using-python).

Also, what's the best way to handle the outliers other than discarding the rows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'outlier' does not directly mean 'invalid data point'. Instead, it means the datapoint is simply showing a value relatively distant from a bulk distribution. Also, what you call 'outliers' is often subjective and problem specific, thus there is no absolute criterion for 'outliers' (i.e. 1.5*IQR is just for box plot visualization purpose). If I oversimplify the reality, there are roughly 3 cases.

1. The outlier is obviously well within the theoretical/practical limit of that instance's nature (e.g. Body temperature of 38.0C where others are in 35.8-36.5C range) and it can be a strong clue for something different is going on (therefore useful for modeling/prediction).
2. The outlier is obviously well outside of the theoretical/practical limit (e.g. Human age of 500) and it should be considered as 'null' value
3. Whether the outlier is inside/outside of the theoretical/practical limit is unknown, so the knowledge of domain experts is necessary (In this case we discuss with technical experts of specific area such as Physicist for Physics problems)

Therefore, there is no universal way to handle 'outliers' based on the definition of box plots, but rather you should learn about the nature of the dataset and decide how to handle it properly.